# Listview - Textblock - Button - FolderBrowserDialog - ObservableCollection Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, mvvm, binding

I am trying to wrap my head around C#-wpf-MVVM.
I am attempting to put it to use with a simple idea I want to implement

1. .csv files stores LocationName, Location for default file locations.
2. .csv is read into a datatable for reference
3. ObservableCollection is created from datatable
4. Listview is bound to ObservableCollection
5. Textblock is bound to SelectedItem.LocationName
6. Button activates a FileDialogBrowser, the result of which I would like to use to update the location of the SelectedItem.LocationName

I have bound the Listview to the ObservableCollection and bound the Textblock to the SelectedItem.
Where I am running into problems is how do I get the result of the FolderDialogBrowser to update the ObservableCollection SelectedItem.LocationName?

If I change the text manually in the Textblock everything works fine...However, if I use codebehind to update the Textblock...no changes are happening.

```
private ObservableCollection<FileLocation > _filelocation;
    private FileLocation  _selectedLocation;

    public ObservableCollection<FileLocation > FileLocations
    {
        get { return _filelocation; }
        set
        {
            _filelocation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Files");
        }
    }

    public FileLocation  SelectedFile
    {
        get { return _selectedLocation; }
        set
        {
            _selectedLocation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedFile");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

   

 FileLocations  = new ObservableCollection<FileLocation>();
        foreach (DataRow row in DtLocations.Rows)
        {
                string LocationDescription = (string)row.ItemArray[0];
                string LocationPath = (string)row.ItemArray[1];
                FileLocations.Add(new FileLocation() { LocationName  = LocationDescription, Location  = LocationPath });
        }
   

<TextBox  x:Name="tbxFileLocation" Tag="FileLocation" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Width="200" Height="23" Foreground="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Text ="{Binding SelectedFile.Location ,Mode=TwoWay }" />
                <Button x:Name="btnFolderLocator" Content="..." Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Width="25" Height=" 23" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="BtnFolderLocator_Click"   />

    

<ListView x:Name="lvwFileLocations" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding FileLocations}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile }" Margin="0">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path= LocationName, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path= Location , Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: `FileLocation` with `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Genusatplay  Thank you.  The comment caused me to experiment on a couple things and I found the error.  Somewhere during my testing I was trying to set the SelectedValue of the Listview since I could not get it to work. This caused a conflict.  Thank you for causing me to change my thinking and get me out of a circular thought.